# How do i create an Environment pipeline to deploy my app to?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

After reading many tutorials over the internet and Learn at Microsoft i managed to create a Build pipeline for a simple ASP .Net Core app.

When this project is pushed it performs a build in DevOps to ensure it can build.

Following this i would like to create an `Environment` or `Pipeline` where i can push this app to a server (or whatever Azure DevOps has to offer) so it can be viewed in a browser. I dont have `Releases` appearing as per most articles.

Most articles dont match what i see on the screen. I have a trial Azure DevOps account for this so not sure if thats limiting what i am seeing or not as the menu is significantly different.

I dont have anything else setup but if anyone feels it may be appropriate to set another service up first then i could do that but im not sure where to look as theres quite a lot of options.

I would like to create a process where i can deploy this app > build it > if successful then deploy this app to a test environment which is running on a Windows Server.

I've read numerous articles including this one which seems to be close to what I need but I don't know how to target a Windows server (if that's the case) or how to set one up https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops

Comment: If I understand well - you want to deploy your application. But... Azure Devops is not cloud where you can deploy sth to. What you want to do is to come up where do you want to deploy your application (it can be AWS, Azure (do not mistake it with Azure Devops) or your on premise machine). Then you can write deployment pipeline.

Comment: For example - if you come up with solution that you want to host it in azure function [there is deployment instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-azure-devops?tabs=csharp%2Cyaml&pivots=v1)

Comment: Looks like very close to what I want to do but I want to go to a Windows server

Comment: Well... ok. But where do you host this WIndows Server? (either premise or cloud)

Comment: Under pipelines, do you see an Environments tab? If so, that's where you can create an environment and register VMs into it. Then you can use a `deployment` job in your YAML to target an environment and run steps across all of the VMs in that environment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I dont have Releases appearing as per most articles.

For the new Created Organization, it will disable the Classic Release Pipeline by default.

To solve this issue, you can refer to the following steps:

Step1: Navigate to **Organization Settings -> Settings**  and disable the option: **Disable creation of classic release pipelines**.  (Organization Level)

Step2: Navigate to target **Project Settings -> Settings** and disable the option: **Disable creation of classic release pipelines** (Project Level)

[image]

Then you will see the Release Option under the Pipelines tab.

[image]

If you are not able to create classic Build Pipeline, you can also disable the option: **Disable creation of classic build pipelines**

> How do i create an Environment pipeline to deploy my app to?

The Pipeline environment can only be used in **YAML** Pipeline.

You can create a virtual Machine type environment first(install the agent on your local windows machine).

[image]

Then you can add the tasks in **YAML Pipeline -> deployment job** to use the target environment to deploy the app to windows machine.

For example:

```
trigger: 
- main

pool: 
   vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- deployment: VMDeploy
  displayName: Deploy to VM
  environment: 
   name: VMenv
   resourceName: VMenv
   resourceType: virtualMachine
  strategy:
     runOnce:
        deploy:   
          steps:
            - task: deployment task
              xxx
```

If you want to use **Release** Pipeline to deploy the app to local machine, you need to use [Deployment Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops) in Release Pipeline.

Refer to this blog: [Using Azure DevOps to Deploy Web Applications to Virtual Machines](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-azure-devops-to-deploy-web-applications-to-virtual-machines/)

**Update:**

When you create the Pipeline environment, you can select the
**Virtual machines** option. It will generate the code to install agent.

[image]

You can copy the Registration script and paste it in PowerShell administrator mode to run it.

Then it will add a target agent in environment.

For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: [Environment - virtual machine resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops)

Comment: I don't want to use the classic Release only new. I created the YAML to target a local VM but what agent do I need to install on local machine?

Comment: @KeithViking Refer to the update in the answer. One choice is that you can use the Virtual Machine type agent in the Pipeline environment. Or you can also use the pipeline self-hosted agent to run your pipeline. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops

Comment: Both these two options can be used in YAML pipeline.